# Count number of comma separated values, divide next cell by that number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in which one column occasionally contains a sequence of numbers separated by commas (Units). I'd like to find a script that will count the amount of values in that cell (Values), then divide the adjacent cell by that amount, ultimately replacing the value of that cell (NeedResult, replacing Values).

I've played around with formulas, but my VBA skills are rudimentary... Any help mucho appreciated!

table image here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really want it, I'm not sure you need a VBA solution for this. The calculation can be done using Excel's formulas: simply subtract the length of the string from the length of it with commas removed. Your cell formula could look something like this:

```
=C3/(LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3,",",""))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the first cell value on the commas and adjust the ubound dimension of the resulting array.

```
dim i as long
i = ubound(split(range("b2").value, chr(44))) + 1
range("d2") = cdbl(range("c2").value / i)
```

Without the compiler directive Option Base 1, a split array is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formula as well

In D2 entered as array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",C2/COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(44), "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s")))
```